# How to check if a cell in DataGridView exist?

Tags: c#, datagridview

I have a static method that check the sum of an given column. I am using it on event `RowsAdded`  but I got the following error:

```
System.NullReferenceException was unhandled
Message=Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
```

Here is my code, please tell me where I am wrong

```
public static decimal datagSum(DataGridView dgv, string colName)
{
    int i = dgv.RowCount - 1, j = 0;
    decimal dgvSum = 0;
    decimal k = 0;
    while (j < i)
    {
        if (dgv.Rows[(i - 1)].Cells.Count > 3)
        {

            if (decimal.TryParse(dgv.Rows[(i - 1)].Cells[colName].Value.ToString(), out k))
            {
                dgvSum += k;
            }
            j++;

        }
    }
    return dgvSum;
}
```

Comment: If you but a breakpoint in at the beginning and hover over each variable you can check which part is null

Comment: When you got this exception, did it not give you line number?

Comment: @GovindaRajbhar: It's great that you're trying to improve other people's posts, but when editing posts, it'd be good to take the time to make sure that you've fixed up all of the formatting issues, as well as making sure that obvious spelling/grammar/punctuation mistakes (such as "i" instead of "I") are fixed -- this helps to make sure that someone else doesn't have to go and edit the post again by getting it right the first time. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Code Snippet

```
if (dataGridView1.Columns[e.ColumnIndex].Name == "CompanyName")
   {
       if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(e.FormattedValue.ToString()))
       {
           dataGridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].ErrorText =
               "Company Name must not be empty";
           e.Cancel = true;
       }
   }
```